# Android AppCompat Dark Theme Settings Checkbox

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have upgraded to v21 on the AppCompat library in the Support Library.  When using the dark theme (@style/Theme.AppCompat), the checkboxes in the SettingsActivity are black so you can't even see them.

This was before the update:

[image]

This is after the update:

[image]

The checkboxes everywhere else in the app are fine.  How do I fix the ones in the SettingsActivity?

Comment: Same problem for me =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the solution on [this page](http://www.michenux.net/android-preferencefragmentcompat-906.html) to create a compatible PreferenceFragment class by copying the code into my project. I then replaced my former PreferenceActivity with a class inheriting from ActionBarActivity and instantiate a Fragment class derived from the new PreferenceCompatFragment class. This now work well to display my preferences with an Action Bar of the expected color as well as checkboxes that are properly accented. Here is the code for my new settings activity:

```
public class SettingsFragActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);
    frame.setId(R.id.content);
    setContentView(frame);
    this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content, new SettingsFragment (), null).commit();
    }


public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceCompatFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
        super.onCreate(paramBundle);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    }
}
```

}

Note that the addPreferencesFromResource belongs to the custom PreferenceFragment class.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your activity is inheriting from `ActionBarActivity`. Inheriting from `Activity` was giving me your effects; inheriting from `ActionBarActivity` fixed the problem. You can see the results in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppCompat/Basic/CheckBox).

Comment: That seems to be the correct reason, but I must be missing something.  I inherit from the SettingsActivity (which obviously inherits from Activity).  It doesn't make a lot of sense to change that to inherit from ActionBarActivity instead.

Comment: @Floss: You will not be able to use the action bar backport with a `PreferenceActivity` (which I presume is what you meant by "SettingsActivity"). Somebody could create an `ActionBarPreferenceActivity` mashup, as a subclass of `ActionBarActivity` that has the functionality of `PreferenceActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that's because the support library is not emulating the Holo theme anymore.

Have you try defining the colorAceent your theme ?

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

   ...

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated,
     which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name=”colorAccent”>@color/accent</item>

   ...

</style>
```

Reference:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com.ar/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html